# Type arguments cannot be inferred for generalized Expression variable

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm getting the following error:

```
the type arguments for method 'Queryable.OrderBy<TSource,TKey>(
    IQueryable<TSource>, Expression<Func<TSource,TKey>>) 
cannot be inferred from the useage.
```

How would I either modify `Me.GetOrder()` or the declaration of `myOrderByVariable` so that it creates a variable that works as a parameter to the `OrderBy()` *without using a custom Extension Method?*  This code is just a test.  I need the variable to send to a foreign repository.

```
void Main()
{
    // Assemble
    string property = "sku";
    var propertyType = Product.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetType();
    var entityType = Product.GetType();

    // Act
    // TODO: begin part to change
    var myOrderByVariable = Me.GetOrder(Product.GetType(), propertyType, property );
    // end part to change

    // Assert
    Product
    .OrderBy( myOrderByVariable )
    .Skip(10).Take(10)
    .Dump();
}

public static class Me
{
    // TODO: begin part to change
    public static Expression<Func<TS, TK>> 
        GetOrder<TS,TK>(TS entity, TK propType, string propertyName)
    {
        //Create x=>x.PropName
        var propertyInfo = typeof(TS).GetProperty(propertyName);
        ParameterExpression arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TS), "x");
        MemberExpression property = Expression.Property(arg, propertyName);
        var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<TS,TK>>(
                       property, new ParameterExpression[] { arg });

        return selector;
    }
    // end part to change
}
```

---

The rest of this are responses to questions.

Addition Edit 1: Product happens to be a POCO drived from a database table using Entity Framework:

```
public partial class Product
{
    public long      sku             { get; set; }
    public string    name            { get; set; }
    public bool      active          { get; set; }
    public int       retailpriceqty  { get; set; }
    public decimal   retailprice     { get; set; }
}
```

Additional Edit 2: How I'm using the variable in [URF Unit of Work & Repositories Framework](https://github.com/lelong37/urf)

```
// in my ASP.NET MVC Controller
// Restful Post instead of Get because query object creates the response
[Route("Product")][HttpPost]
public IEnumerable<ProductVM> GetProductVM(
           [FromBody] QueryObjectVM query )
{
    // QueryObjectVM has a FilterBy string (predicate), OrderBy string,
    // Select string (projection), page size, and page number
    // Select is a TODO until I get dynamic mapping working, which is next

    var queryby = QueryService.CleanupQuery( query);

    var filterby = Spec.FilterBy<Product>( queryby.FilterBy);
    var orderby  = Spec.OrderBy<Product>( queryby.OrderBy);

    // Could possibly inject .OrderBy("sku") via Dynamic Linq,
    // but would repository understand it?
    var result = _productService
        .Query( filterby )
        .OrderBy( o => o.OrderBy( orderby) ) // .OrderBy ( o => o.OrderBy(oo => oo.sku))
        .Select( ProductVM.Map)
        .Skip( (queryby.page - 1) * queryby.pageSize)
        .Take( queryby.pageSize)
        ;
    return result;
}
```

Edit: This works with Microsoft [Dynamic Linq](https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic) Extension Methods, but we want a non-extension method answer.  NetMage at one point answered with a method that returned an `object` data type that worked great for variables derived from objects like `string`, but `long` and `int` still failed.  Maybe using `dynamic` instead of `object` as a method return type would work?  Possible?

```
var result = _Product
             .Query(filter)
             .OrderBy(o => o.OrderBy(s.Count > 0 ? s[0] : "first_field")
                           .OrderBy(s.Count > 1 ? s[1] : "second_field")
                           .OrderBy(s.Count > 2 ? s[2] : "third_field")
                           .OrderBy(s.Count > 3 ? s[3] : "forth_field")
                           .OrderBy(s.Count > 4 ? s[4] : "fifth_field"))
             .SelectPage(ProductVM.Map, query.page, query.pageSize, out count)
;
return result;
```

Comment: Your problem with your example is you are mixing compile time and runtime types improperly. Consider your first parameter to `Me.GetOrder` - `Product.GetType()`. The type of the expression is `Type` so that means `TS` is `Type` and you are doing `typeof(Type)` in your creation of `arg`, which is obviously not what is intended.

Comment: What type is `Product`?

Comment: @NetMage Product is a POCO derived from a database table.  Entity Framework connects the POCO to the database.  I will add the class definition.

Comment: Can you provide sample code/more details about how the variable is passed to the foreign repository?

Comment: @NetMage added how I'm calling it.

Comment: Inside my current answer, I essentially create `s => s.OrderBy(x => x.sku)` then compile and invoke it. Perhaps if I just returned that expression instead? Modified answer to return the lambda. Change your code to say `OrderBy(orderby)` and assign the result of the `MyOrderByLambda` to `query.OrderBy`.

Comment: Testing seems to indicate you can't use `.OrderBy(o => o.OrderBy(orderby))` ? The return type of `o.OrderBy(...)` is `IOrderedQueryable<>` which isn't usable by `OrderBy`?

Comment: @NetMage I did alter Microsoft's Dynamic Linq to make OrderBy() return IOrderedQueryable instead of IQueryable, which allows `.OrderBy(o => o.OrderBy("sku"))` and this works but I really don't want to use an extension method.  I really think you're on to something with returning an `object` data type which was perfect and worked except for non-objects.  Maybe we could use `dynamic` instead of `object` and make it work?

Comment: Using `dynamic` instead of `object` results in the same error for `int32` and I assume `long`. `dynamic` still assumes a class object.

Comment: Can you give the full type for the outer `OrderBy()` in the call?

Comment: @NetMage it is a big answer, linked in the URF Unit of Work & Repositories Framework under `IQueryFluent`.  I added the code that does work with Extension methods to set a limit on that train of thought.  LOL.  Hopefully there's a way to simply create a variable that represents the orderby parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your function that creates an `Expression<Func>` for the `OrderBy` parameter with a function that creates the entire `OrderBy` expression lambda and then pass that to your repository.

In class `Me`,

```
public static Expression<Func<IQueryable<TS>,IOrderedQueryable<TS>>> MyOrderByLambda<TS>(IQueryable<TS> _, string propertyName) {
    //Create x=>x.PropName
    var argx = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TS), "x");
    var property = Expression.PropertyOrField(argx, propertyName);
    var selector = Expression.Lambda(property, new ParameterExpression[] { argx });

    //Create s=>s.OrderBy<TS, propertyInfo.Type>(x => x.@propertyName)
    var args = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IQueryable<TS>), "s");
    var genericOrderByMI = typeof(Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public).First(mi => mi.Name == "OrderBy" && mi.GetParameters().Length == 2);
    var orderByMI = genericOrderByMI.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TS), property.Type);
    var orderbybody = Expression.Call(orderByMI, args, selector);
    var orderbyLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<IQueryable<TS>, IOrderedQueryable<TS>>>(orderbybody, args);
    return orderbyLambda;
}
```

Comment: What happens when the datatype is not derived from an Object, like an Int64 / long (SKU happens to be an Int64 which I will add to the question above)?  I believe this would work for a String datatype.

Comment: You will get an error because long can't be an object.

Comment: I updated my answer to create the `OrderBy` expression dynamically and then compile/run it to product the proper answer, regardless of type, though I now see it won't work if you want to pass it to another library.

Comment: I cannot use an extension method, but if I could I would have used Dynamic Linq .OrderBy("sku").  The repository (or Entity Framework) does not understand Dynamic Linq.

Comment: What about using a dynamic keyword for the return data type instead of using object?  Your object return type definitely worked for variables based on object.